# Are Questions Regarding The New Jolla Smartphone Applicable?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions regarding the new [Jolla](http://jolla.com/) smartphone running [Sailfish OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS) applicable here at Android Enthusiasts ?

Comment: Is Sailfish related to Android? It seems to be just another (smartphone) OS using the Linux Kernel. If so, I would consider it off-topic on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: Though it's capable of running Android apps, I doubt it would be well suited here. Our site is about Android from a users view, not primarily about apps (in fact, e.g. asking for app recommendations is even explicitly off topic here). So I tend to agree with Flow.

Comment: @Izzy Thats exactly the reason I thought I would ask :)

Comment: I wonder if there might be a place for questions about app behavior or such OSes, but I'm agreed with others that the OS in general is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

I say **no**.

BlackBerry 10 is supposed to be able to run Android apps, and we don't accept questions about that here.

Stack Exchange sites do best when they're focused enough that they can attract experts, but not so focused that there's not enough content. I have a feeling that Sailfish-related questions would simply languish here, unloved and unanswered.

(If it's big enough, suggesting a Sailfish OS site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) would not go amiss.)

But no, I don't think Jolla or any Sailfish OS device is on-topic here.

Comment: All that said, I am just one member of the community. If someone can craft a compelling counterargument I'd love to see it.

Comment: I think what you have said is very sensible. It will be interesting to see whether Jolla takes off in a big way, as the handset is quite expensive.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: I do agree with what you have said, the only counter I can think (off the top of my head) is that Android is starting on a branching path potentially. CyanogenMod is an Android distribution but it is gradually becoming its own subsection of Andriod. It may become its own OS in time. We still factor it in and have a tag, but when is it not Android enough? I guess the same could, in theory, apply to Salifish in that regard.